# Makefile recursive method issue

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Below is my code structure with Makefile and source codes

```
work
├── code
|     | 
|     └── main.h and test.h files here
│     └── main.c and test.c files here
|     └── subdir.mk
|
├── _build/
      └── Makefile here
```

Makefile looks like below

```
all : ../code/target_file

../code/target_file : ../code/main.o ../code/test.o
    @echo Building ...
    @echo Linking files ...
    gcc -Llib ../code/main.o ../code/test.o -lm -o ../code/target_file  

.PHONY:subdir
../code/main.o ../code/test.o:subdir;
subdir:
    @echo Building object files ...
    cd ../code && $(MAKE) -f subdir.mk 

clean:
    rm -rv ../code/*.o ../code/*.exe
```

subdir.mk code is

```
main.o : main.c main.h test.h
    @echo Building main.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c main.c -o main.o

test.o : test.c test.h
    @echo Building test.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c test.c -o test.o
```

I am trying to use recursive make as per the tutorials and suggestions in the forum.

The error I am getting is

```
Building object files ... 

cd ../code && make -f subdir.mk

make[1]: Entering directory '/f/My_Work/C/VSC/makefile_test/Recursive/test_mulltiple_2020_09_19/code'

Building main.c ...

gcc -Werror -Wall -c main.c -o main.o

make[1]: Leaving directory '/f/My_Work/C/VSC/makefile_test/Recursive/test_mulltiple_2020_09_19/code'

Building ...

Linking files ...

gcc -Llib ../code/main.o ../code/test.o -lm -o ../code/target_file
____________________________________________________________
gcc.exe: error: ../code/test.o: No such file or directory   |
                                                            |
make: *** [Makefile:7: ../code/target_file] Error 1         |
____________________________________________________________|
```

main.o is generated but test.o didn't.

Any suggestions for removing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your subdir.mk file lists two targets.  Make will always build either the target(s) you give on the command line, or else the first target in the makefile if you don't specify.

So you either have to create an initial target in your subdir.mk like this:

```
all: main.o test.o
```

so that it will build both, or else tell the recursive make invocation you want to build them both:

```
subdir:
        @echo Building object files ...
        cd ../code && $(MAKE) -f subdir.mk test.o main.o
```

Comment: The target doesn't have to be named `all`, it can be whatever you want: `all` has a long tradition in makefiles however.